# Why is n=1 at a low pressure in the Freundlich Isotherm Equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry

On the topic of adsorption of a gas over a solid, the **Freundlich isotherm** explains this behaviour in an approximate manner via the following equation
$$ \frac{x}{m} = kP^{1/n} \tag{1} $$
where $x$ is the mass adsorbed, $m$ is the mass of the adsorbent, $P$ is the equilibrium pressure of the adsorbate, and $k$ and $n$ are the constants of the model.

The factor $1/n$ can have values between $0$ and $1$ (probable range from $0.1$ to $0.5$). What is the reasoning, that for a low pressure of gas, then we may set $1/n = 1$ or $n=1$?